# What is a "51% spawn camp attack", and is it any different from a normal 51% attack

Tags: attacks, forks

What is a "51% spawn camp attack", and is it any different from a normal 51% attack. Saw this mentioned in [this](https://twitter.com/VitalikButerin/status/839968402152148992) tweet from Vitalik.

Is there a distinction that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A month prior to the tweet you mention, Vitalik had [tweeted](https://twitter.com/vitalikbuterin/status/827783678910558208?lang=en-gb) the following:

> Suggested vocabulary item: spawn camping attack. When a 51% miner
>   cartel keeps attacking over and over again, rendering the chain
>   useless.

So technically no different to your bog-standard 51% attack, it's just repeated *ad infinitum*. (Or at least until some point when further attacks are considered unnecessary.)